# Contract Testing: Modifying State variable and using arguments

Tags: testing

I tested the following contract on an online tool:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract Calculator{
   int private lastValue =0;
   function Add(int a, int b) public returns (int){
      lastValue = a+ b;
      return lastValue;
   }
   function Subtract(int a, int b) public returns (int) {
      lastValue = a-b;
      return lastValue;
    }
    function LastOperation()public constant returns (int) {
       return lastValue;
    }
 }
```

I got following messages:

> 1)Contract fields that can be modified by any user must be inspected. 
>   2) Method arguments must be sanitized before they are used in
>   computations.

Somebody please guide me how to modify the contract based upon the above messages?

Zulfi.

Comment: It might help if you said what "online tool" gave you those messages.

Comment: SmartCheck: https://tool.smartdec.net/scan/a56820dd71574470979ad6be69b79038